# How to troubleshoot missing DLLs in output folder?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, build, cmake

I've cloned a repo of an open source project and have gotten it to build.
I then decided to go to an earlier branch but now DLL files are missing from the output folder.
*My understanding of cmake and building c/c++ is very limited.*

I can't find any relevant differences in the `CmakeLists` file however in the `cmake_install` file I can tell that the missing DLLs are shown in one file and not the other.
Building `Debug` instead of `Release` in VS produces some of the DLLs that are missing but not all of them (and with a 'd' in the file name).

How can I troubleshoot this? What files do I look in?
*If there's some easy to digest information on the subject that would also help, though I hope I won't need it for this specific issue.*

Comment: start from name of missing dll. Google it what it is and confront this with the project. Your question is missing so many details, that it is impossible to help.